# How to insert a word document into MarkLogic?

Tags: ms-word, insert, document, marklogic

We are trying to insert a word document into MarkLogic , but we are not sure how to do it, we have searched many sites but we have not got any feasible answers.

Comment: Please share a code snippet of what you tried, preferably by updating your question..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't really matter what kind of document is being loaded: all the load APIs work the same. So you could use `xdmp:load` e.g. `xdmp:load("/home/whoever/foo.docx","/dbpath/foo.docx")`

Since this is a binary file, it won't be particularly searchable. If you want to make it searchable, there is a CPF pipeline that unzips the docx and cleans it up a bit. See [CPF documentation](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/cpf)